# Cakephp 3: currency precision in view

Tags: cakephp-3.0, currency-formatting

I have values in a database for example: 830,400,000 and in the view I want to display it as $830.4

In the view I thought to use the pattern option but I was unclear how to use it:

```
<td class="nonBulletList">
    <?= $this->Number
             ->currency($currentExpenses, 
                        'USD', 
                        ['places' => 1], 
                        ['pattern' => '###.#']) ?>
</td>
```

Comment: If you always need to divide by a million, just use `$currentExpenses / 1000000`?

Comment: what is exactly stored in the database? and is it a string, integer, float?

Comment: it is an integer

Comment: and you store 830400000? and you want to show it as 830.4? why. the code you show is correct, but they will show it as 830,400,000.0 as you would expect

Comment: This data is used in a few views which require the full amount, but in this view it states that the chart is in Millions so $ 830.4 millions. So I don't want 830,400,000.0 I'm looking for 830.4

Comment: Greg your solution worked <?= $this->Number->currency($currentExpenses/1000000, 'USD', ['places' => 1]) ?> if you add it as an answer I can accept it and give you credit.